# Copy embedded image without using Shapes

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with many sheets and images that have random names and arbitrary order, the only image that I need is always in the range A2:C14, I'm using the following code to copy the image:

```
firstSheet.Range("A2:C14").Copy
secondSheet.Range("I6").PasteSpecial
```

But it only copies the cell text, not the image.
Is there a way to copy an image using `Range("A2:C14)"` or another way to select the cell to copy the image?

Comment: AFAIK the only way to do it is to loop through the shapes and test for `.TopLeftCell = Range("A2")` to find the one you want to copy.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman pretty easy with shapes... but he dont want to use it... knowing it is a shape, i dont know how you can do...

Comment: @DirkReichel - yes, I know. Edited my comment to be more clear in my thoughts :)

Comment: I was looking for something easier. I've discovered the method `.CopyPicture`, it does what I want, but before it finishes going through all the sheets, I get the error "PasteSpecial method of Range class failed", that method almost completed the task.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman That is the answer, you should post it as such.  Note for OP: `CopyPicture` is a method of a `Shape` object.  So unless (s)he already has a pointer to it, using the `Shapes` collection is unavoidable

Comment: @chrisneilsen I meant without using shapes because I thought that if you use shapes you have to provide the image name(or number), isn't there really a way to copy an image from a cell by just using the cell range where the image is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `CopyPicture` is a method of a Shape object, unless you already have a pointer to it, using the Shapes collection is unavoidable

Something like this

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = firstSheet.Range("A2:C14")
    For Each shp In firstSheet.Shapes
        If Not Intersect(rng, shp.TopLeftCell) Is Nothing Then
            ' Found it
            shp.CopyPicture
            secondSheet.Range("I6").PasteSpecial

            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: beat me to posting it as an answer :)  To add to the answer, the only way to refer to the cell location of a shape is by the Shapes [TopLeftCell Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa197363(v=office.11).aspx), in which you also need to refer to the Shapes collection for.

Comment: no apology necessary at all. just happy OP got the correct answer ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, Scott and Chris.